# Migrating Repositories from various systems to Git

Tags: svn, github, tfs, perforce, gitlab

I was wondering if anyone's had any experience moving code repositories from various different version control services (such as Perforce, SVN, TFS etc) to a single open source solution (in this case GitLab)

What was your experience like, and do you have any advice for someone attempting to do so. I've read up on how to do it, I'm just looking at more of a justification and previous experience (has it benefited you, etc)

Answer (score 0):

For TFS, I haven't migrate from TFS to GitLab, but I have migrated a project from TFVC to GitHub. You can use the same steps to migrate to GitLab, check the green line highlight:

[image]

You can also clean up some files after clone the repository, check this blog:

http://chriskirby.net/blog/migrate-an-existing-project-from-tfs-to-github-with-changeset-history-intact